# How can I do sendAndReceive with Spring EventListener?

Tags: spring, event-handling

With the (meanwhile deprecated) reactor-bus from project-reactor I had the API `eventBus.sendAndReceive(Event e, Consumer<?> callback)`.

This allowed to trigger execution by publishing an event and automatically subscribe to a response.

With Spring eventListeners I can publish another event from an EventListener method, but I am missing the feature to directly subscribe to a return value.

How do I achieve the same behaviour with spring? How do I programmaticcaly register/unregister listeners and how do I make the topics dynamic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Spring's [`ApplicationEventMulticaster`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/event/SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java#L136) you can't subscribe to a response. You probably noticed that the [`onApplicationEvent` method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html#onApplicationEvent-E-) returns `void`! The reason for this is because literally all it does is either call the Subscriber (i.e. `ApplicationListener`) synchronously, or runs the listener method asynchronously on an executor without returning any type of `Future`.

Spring's [Project Reactor](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/) evolved a while ago to match the [Reactive Manifesto](https://www.reactivemanifesto.org/) and similar frameworks (like RxJava) more closely. Now with Spring 5 (with which Reactor comes with by default) you can use Reactor and RxJava interchangeably.

That being the case, regarding your questions:

> How do I achieve the same behaviour with spring?

You use the new version of [Reactor Core](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/) and the functional programming features of `Flux`, `Mono`, etc.

> With Spring eventListeners I can publish another event from an
>   EventListener method, but I am missing the feature to directly
>   subscribe to a return value.

If you [look at the API for `Flux`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/index.html?reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html), you'll see that it has a fluent and functional API (in some ways similar to Java 8 streams).

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
  .map(value -> value + 1)
  .subscribe(subscriber::function);
```

This way, you can operate on your "events" (i.e. 1,2,3,4 in this example), perform an operation on what would be a "return value" for those events, and then pipe those to some subscriber operation to consume those events.

> How do I programmaticcaly register/unregister listeners and how do I
>   make the topics dynamic?

You should take a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279767/reactor-way-to-cancel-subscriptions).
To register/unregister, that's something you can do with what you might call "completors" in the Reactor framework. See the [`take` functions](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/) in the Reactor API. They will signal upstream that they basically want to be unsubscribed, and that the upstream producer should stop emitting.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear ... but at least I can give up trying now ... thanks